# Controlling Arduino Mega Ramps 1.4 using Johnny-five

Tags: arduino, johnny-five

I want to control a [Arduino Mega](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega) with a [Ramps 1.4](http://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS_1.4) shield using Johnny-five.
I uploaded the Standard Firmata the Arduino board and tried to run this code:

```
var five = require('johnny-five');
var board = new five.Board();
board.on('ready',function(){
   console.log('Board is ready');
});
```

My error:

```
1448365609699 Device(s) COM3,COM5
1448365609707 Connected COM3
1448365619710 Device or Firmware Error A timeout occurred while connecting to the Board.
Please check that you've properly flashed the board with the correct firmware.
See: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started#trouble-shooting
enter code here
events.js:146
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])
at Board.emit (events.js:144:17)
at Board.log (C:\Users\Digital Hammer\Documents\Electric lab playground\test\node_modules\johnny-five\lib\board.js:633:8)
at Board.(anonymous function) [as error] (C:\Users\Digital Hammer\Documents\Electric lab playground\test\node_modules\johnny-five\lib\board.js:644:14)
at Board.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Digital Hammer\Documents\Electric lab playground\test\node_modules\johnny-five\lib\board.js:414:14)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: Dumb question but.. What is the arduino mega com port?

Comment: It is com5. I saw a problem here now. Com3 is connected

Comment: Well, it looks like it's trying to access it on com5, so this should be fixed before looking for other errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var five = require('johnny-five');
var board = new five.Board({
port :"com5"
});
board.on('ready',function(){
console.log('Board is ready');
});
```

The js file didn't connect to the correct port. I need to set it to the one which is COM5.